# Make a parametric vector drawable

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

Is it possible to make a parametric vector drawable in Android? For example, define a complex shape in XML and then change its color and shape programatically depending on application state.

Comment: `Drawable#setColorFilter`

Comment: @pksink changing a color was just an example, updated the question

Answer (score -1):

In xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <item android:id="@+id/circle_bg">
            <shape android:shape="oval" >
                <solid android:color="@color/white" />

                <corners android:radius="40dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>


    </layer-list>
```

In java class

```
 view.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.circle_xml));
 LayerDrawable bgDrawable = (LayerDrawable) view.getBackground();
        final GradientDrawable shape = (GradientDrawable) bgDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.circle_bg);
        shape.setColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: Changing a color was just an example. I meant change any vector drawable attribute that's changable in an animated drawable. Updated the question.

Comment: By accessing Id you can change any thing. Just like setcolor function is there similarly for other attributes like setshape, setgradient we have more functions and you can make change according to situation. This was just example how to access id of drawable.